# How to pass a specific default argument in a function?

Tags: c++, function

I know that I am supposed to pass the arguments in order to change the default value, but let's say I want to keep the first value and change the second one:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(char = '*', int = 3);

int main() {
    int count = 5;

    cout << "No argument passed: ";
    // *, 3 will be parameters
    display();

    cout << "First argument passed: ";
    // #, 3 will be parameters
    display('#');

    cout << "Both arguments passed: ";
    // $, 5 will be parameters
    display('$', count);

    cout << "Second argument passed: ";
    // here is the problem where i need to only pass the second argument
    display(count);

    return 0;
}

void display(char c, int count) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
    {
        cout << c;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can't be done in general. For some argument types you can provide a second overload of the function talking only the second argument.

Comment: No, you cannot omit the first argument and pass the second. Only the trailing arguments can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

With only two arguments, it's rather easy to overload the function to allow parameters in either order.

```
void display(char = '*', int = 3);
void display(int count, char c = '*') { display( c, count ); }
```

This change will also make your program *correctly fail* if you accidentally pass two `int`s or two `char`s or something similarly ambiguous.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3vec9ThK8)

Comment: Note that this is not `std::invoke`-friendly.

Comment: @bitmask that's valid, although the default parameters in the question are already unfriendly to `std::invoke`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the named argument idiom that is possible since C++20:

```
struct DisplayArguments {
  char c = '*'; // choose a more speaking name maybe
  int count = 3;
};

void display(DisplayArguments = {});

int main() {
  display({}); // '*', 3
  display({.count = 5}); // '*', 5
}
```

Comment: Note: This idiom is using a feature more formally known as ["designated initializers"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)